# mplayer: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: video-player, shared-libraries

I'm getting the following error:

```
mplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libvdpau.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Most likely it happened after manually installing `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.135.run`.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `libvdpau1` package. For instance, via the command line

```
sudo apt install libvdpau1
```

Comment: libvdpau1 is already the newest version.
libvdpau1 set to manually installed.
BTW. there are a bit more informative explanation and provided output:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908250/mplayer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libvdpau-so-1-cannot-open-shared

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing symlink. You can solve it this way:

```
user@host:~$ cd /usr/lib
user@host:/usr/lib$ sudo ln -s vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.304.135 libvdpau.so.1
```